# Why does malloc seem to not be creating a new variable?

Tags: c, malloc

Really dumb question.  Here's my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sample {
  int a;
  int b;
} SAMPLE_T;

int main() {
  int i, max = 4;
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
  {
     SAMPLE_T * newsamp = (SAMPLE_T *)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE_T));
     printf("addr: %x\n", &newsamp);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to 'create' a new variable each time I go through the loop, and I thought that this would do the trick, since `malloc` would create a new variable on the heap.  But, it seems I've messed something up.  Here's the output:

```
addr: bfc29c4
addr: bfc29c4
addr: bfc29c4
addr: bfc29c4
```

Am I not understanding how `malloc` is working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address of newsamp is not changing, which is not surprising.  Try:

```
 printf("addr: %x\n", newsamp)
```

Also, even though this is obviously just a toy program you really should free the memory before the loop terminates.

Comment: Right.  Its in the 'real' code, but I'm definitely making sure to free.  Thanks.

Comment: It is better to use "%p" while printing addresses.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are printing the address of the pointer `newsamp` (!!!!) which is a variable on the stack of `main`. It's always the same.

You want to print the pointer itself instead:

```
printf("addr: %x\n", newsamp);
```

Comment: Ah, I was right about the really dumb question part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `printf("addr: %x\n", newsamp);`

You should not do `&newsamp` because that is taking the address of the pointer, not what it points to.